# Python Bokeh - Assign taptool to a subset of Glyphs

Tags: python, bokeh

Hi have  a timeserie to which I add circle glyphs, representing 2 different type of data.

I already managed to assign a different tooltip to each of them by using the suggestion presented here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37558475/4961888

I was hoping I could use a similar syntax to assign a specific subset of the glyph to a taptool, that would bring me to a url present in the source of those glyphs.

so I tried:

```
    fig = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", height=200, tools="tap")
    fig.line(x_range, y_range)  
    news_points = fig.circle(x='timestamp', y='y', fill_color="green", size=5, source=news_source)

    url = "@url"
    taptool = fig.select(type=TapTool)
    taptool.renderers.append(news_points)
    taptool.callback = OpenURL(url=url)
```

But i receive:

```
AttributeError: '_list_attr_splat' object has no attribute 'renderers'
```

It seems to me that the taptool has a different way of being assigned glyphs than the hovertool, and I couldn't find any documentation on the web regarding my problem. I would be glad if someone with a better grip of the package could help me wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fig.select` returns a list, so you'll want to access the first (and only, I'd assume) element.

```
fig = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", height=200, tools="tap")
fig.line(x_range, y_range)  
news_points = fig.circle(x='timestamp', y='y', fill_color="green", size=5, source=news_source)

url = "@url"
taptool = fig.select(type=TapTool)[0]
taptool.renderers.append(news_points)
taptool.callback = OpenURL(url=url)
```

OR

```
fig = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", height=200, tools="tap")
fig.line(x_range, y_range)  
news_points = fig.circle(x='timestamp', y='y', fill_color="green", size=5, source=news_source)

url = "@url"
taptool = fig.select_one(TapTool)
taptool.renderers.append(news_points)
taptool.callback = OpenURL(url=url)
```

Comment: no i don't think so. This is the correct way as per the documentation: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html#openurl

Comment: It looks like that part of the user guide is out-of-date (it's not super clear to me why the example works). Here's the reference docs though: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/plots.html#bokeh.models.plots.Plot.select

Comment: This does not seem to work with Bokeh 0.13.0 says ```str has no attribute append```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bokeh 0.13.0 you achieve this by assigning the renderers as a list. Instead of `taptool.renderers.append(glyph)` You can do `taptool.renderers= [glyph,]`

Something along the lines

````
fig = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", height=200, tools="tap")
fig.line(x_range, y_range)  
news_points = fig.circle(x='timestamp', y='y', fill_color="green", size=5, 
source=news_source)

url = "@url"
taptool = fig.select(type=TapTool)[0]
taptool.renderers= [news_points,]
taptool.callback = OpenURL(url=url)```
````

Otherwise you might get an extra error `str has no attribute append` 
From the [documentation](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/tools.html) renderers can also accept a list, This is especially important where you have multiple renderers on the graph otherwise it takes all the renderers on the plot.